# How to create an aws security group rule allowing RDP ports from anywhere using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need to create aws security group rule resource `aws_security_group_rule`, attach it to AWS EC2 Windows instance and be able to RDP into it from anywhere.

*sg.tf*

```
resource "aws_security_group" "My_VPC_Security_Group" {
  vpc_id       = aws_vpc.My_VPC.id
  name         = "My VPC Security Group"
  description  = "My VPC Security Group"

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following where `3389` is default RDP port:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "My_VPC_Security_Group" {
  vpc_id       = aws_vpc.My_VPC.id
  name         = "My VPC Security Group"
  description  = "My VPC Security Group"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 3389
    to_port     = 3389
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }  

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

}
```

Comment: But such a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me, which creates security group rules using `aws_security_group_rule` as I wanted.

```
resource "aws_security_group" "My_VPC_Security_Group" {
  vpc_id       = aws_vpc.My_VPC.id
  name         = "My VPC Security Group"
  description  = "My VPC Security Group"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_rule" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 3389
  to_port           = 3389
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.My_VPC_Security_Group.id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "egress_rule" {
  type              = "egress"
  from_port         = 0
  to_port           = 0
  protocol          = "-1"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.My_VPC_Security_Group.id
}
```